# Using D3 to make a colored force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

How can I make a **colored** force directed layout using **D3.v4** and **canvas**?

I am not sure how to color the nodes.

We can use this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f584aa36df54c451c94a9d0798caed35) as a reference.

Adding color into this function:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

function drawNode(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = function(d) {
    // d.group is either a 1 or a 2
    return color(d.group)
  }
  context.fill()
}
```

The above code makes the graphic really laggy so I am thinking that that is not the best way to do it. Additionally, the above code colors all nodes in same color even if they are in separate groups.

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/ThePenguin1140/Stanley/blob/master/index.html)

Edit: for clarity, I'd like to use canvas for performance reasons. I've managed to get it to work with SVGs but that makes panning and zooming very slow.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what an example of d.group looks like, and how the _color_ method is implemented.

Comment: I've linked the full code and also added code to explain the color method.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help for the performance without seeing the whole application. But for the color issue, the solution is:

```
  context.fillStyle = color(d.group)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `context.beginPath()` to the function.

The final function now looks like this:

```
function drawNode(d) {
    context.fillStyle = color(d.group);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
    if(d.group == 1){
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, 17 * Math.log(1.25 * Math.pow(d.winCount, 0.25)) + 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }else{
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3.75 * Math.log(Math.pow(d.winCount, 0.75)) + 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }
    context.fill();
}
```